# How to cache data and fetch in reactnative?

Tags: react-native, caching

I am new to Reactnative and Javascript and I am trying to cache the data from APi and get it. But it is not working. I could not render the data. I am getting the error. How can I cache and retrieve data from cache when there is no internent? I have implemented the code for caching as follows:[image]

```
export default class ViewpagerP extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [] }
}
async componentDidMount() {
    const photoStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos')
            console.log(photoStorage);
    if(!photoStorage) {
      try {
        console.log("Null inside")
        const photoResp = await axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        console.log(photoResp)
        const photoData = await JSON.stringify(photoResp.data);
        this.setState({data:photoResp,isLoading:false})
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('GalleryPhotos', photoData);
      } catch(e) {
        console.warn("fetch Error: ", error)
     }
   then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data,isLoading:false }))
   }else{
       this.getPhotos;
   }
 }
 getPhotos = async()=> {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos'));
        this.setState({data:data,isLoading:false})
        console.log(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }

    console.log(this.state.data);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
                loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={6000}
                images={this.state.data}
                customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                    <View key={index} style={[style, styles.customSlideStyle]}>
                        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                            <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
                            <View style={styles.textContainerStyle}>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
                }

            />

        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you have
`then(response => this.setState({ data: response.data,isLoading:false }))` ?

Comment: So that I could store the response data

Comment: If im not wrong, you don't have to use `item.image`. Setting `<Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.customImage} /> ` will do? Because the item consist of everything you pass inside images prop

Comment: What does `console.log(this.state.data)` prints?

Comment: how could I get the image tag with out using  item.image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You need some correction in code**

```
  this.getPhotos;
```

to

```
this.getPhotos();
```

And also you can check internate is on off by using

```
import { NetInfo} from 'react-native';
```

Check the below artical it will help you
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/dailyjs/offline-notice-in-react-native-28a8d01e8cd0)

here is come correction

```
 export default class ViewpagerP extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [] }
}
async componentDidMount() {
    const photoStorage = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos')
            console.log(photoStorage);
    if(!photoStorage) {
      try {
        console.log("Null inside")
        const photoResp = await axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
        console.log(photoResp)
        const photoData = await JSON.stringify(photoResp.data);
        this.setState({data:photoResp,isLoading:false})
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('GalleryPhotos', photoData);
      } catch(e) {
        console.warn("fetch Error: ", error)
     }
   }else{
       this.getPhotos();
   }
 }
 getPhotos = async()=> {
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('GalleryPhotos'));
        this.setState({data:data,isLoading:false})
        console.log(data);
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading) {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 20 }}>
                <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
        )
    }

    console.log(this.state.data);

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ImageSlider style={styles.viewPagerStyle}
                loopBothSides
                autoPlayWithInterval={6000}
                images={this.state.data}
                customSlide={({ index, item, style, width }) => (
                    <View key={index} style={[style, styles.customSlideStyle]}>
                        <View style={styles.contentContainer}>
                            <Image source={{ uri: item.image }} style={styles.customImage} />
                            <View style={styles.textContainerStyle}>
                                <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{item.title}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                )
                }

            />

        </View>
    );
}
}
```

Comment: But I am getting the above mentioned error for getting the data for the very first time

Comment: I am getting "undefined " in the console at the render for the very first time

Comment: componentDidMount call after first run , so you need to check data length.
like 
this.state.data.length > 0 ? then render your slider : <ActivityIndicator />

Comment: How to fetch the new data if the data from api is changed? either added or deleted?

Comment: Its little bit tricky,  whenever data change you need to remove old data,
you need to send some push notification type thing ,
after receive update push notification you need to remove data , which is store.

Comment: Please suggest me how can I achieve it to the same code above

Comment: And also you can check the length of return array if it will be different then you can update Storage. but its not correct. it will not work every time . Like if data length save.

Comment: What is the better method to achieve so?